# Group combinations and count them

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have a weather type table:

```
BaseVar | BaseDate | BaseAttr1 | BaseAttr2 | DependVar | DependDate | DependAttr1 | DependAttr2 |

VarA        01/01      -1           -1        VarA        01/01         -1         -1      
VarA        01/01      -1           -1        VarB        01/01          1          1   
VarA        01/01      -1           -1        VarC        01/01         -1         -1   
VarB        01/01       1            1        VarA        01/01         -1         -1      
VarB        01/01       1            1        VarB        01/01          1          1   
VarB        01/01       1            1        VarC        01/01         -1         -1   
VarC        01/01      -1           -1        VarA        01/01         -1         -1      
VarC        01/01      -1           -1        VarB        01/01          1          1   
VarC        01/01      -1           -1        VarC        01/01         -1         -1

VarA        01/02      -1            1        VarA        01/02       -1            1      
VarA        01/02      -1            1        VarB        01/02       -1           -1   
VarA        01/02      -1            1        VarC        01/02       -1           -1   
VarB        01/02      -1           -1        VarA        01/02       -1            1      
VarB        01/02      -1           -1        VarB        01/02       -1           -1   
VarB        01/02      -1           -1        VarC        01/02       -1           -1   
VarC        01/02      -1           -1        VarA        01/02       -1            1      
VarC        01/02      -1           -1        VarB        01/02       -1           -1   
VarC        01/02      -1           -1        VarC        01/02       -1           -1

.
.
.
.
.
All the way to 12/30
```

There is a "1 to many" type relationship where the BaseVar has many DependVar's. My objective is when a 'BaseVar + WhichBaseAttr + VaseValue' combination occurs, count each of the 'DependAttr1 + WhichDependAttr + DependantValue' combinations that occur. At the end count them all up so I can see when this combination occurs.... these combinations also occur this many times. So one an given day all the variables (VarA, VarB, VarC) recieve one value into each their Attr1 and Attr2 columns (value can be 1 or -1). I have provided a partial result (as there are too many combinations) to better see what I am trying to accomplish. I want to transform my data from the first table into the table below. I have tried different groupings but can't get it work.

```
BaseVar | WhichBaseAttr| BaseValue| BaseAttrCount() | DependVar | WhichDependAttr | DependantValue| DependAttrCount()|
VarA        BaseAttr1      1        0                VarA         DependAttr1         1              0
VarA        BaseAttr1      1        0                VarA         DependAttr1         -1             0
VarA        BaseAttr1      -1       2                VarA         DependAttr1         1              0
VarA        BaseAttr1      -1       2                VarA         DependAttr1         -1             2

VarA        BaseAttr2      1        1                VarA         DependAttr1         1              1
VarA        BaseAttr2      1        1                VarA         DependAttr1         -1             0
VarA        BaseAttr2      -1       1                VarA         DependAttr1         1              0
VarA        BaseAttr2      -1       1                VarA         DependAttr1         -1             1

VarA        BaseAttr2      1        1                VarA         DependAttr2         1              1
VarA        BaseAttr2      1        1                VarA         DependAttr2         -1             0
VarA        BaseAttr2      -1       1                VarA         DependAttr2         1              0
VarA        BaseAttr2      -1       1                VarA         DependAttr2         -1             1

VarA        BaseAttr1      1        0                VarA         DependAttr2          1             0
VarA        BaseAttr1      1        0                VarA         DependAttr2         -1             0
VarA        BaseAttr1      -1       2                VarA         DependAttr2         1              1
VarA        BaseAttr1      -1       2                VarA         DependAttr2         -1             1

(Next seqeuence would be : )

VarA                                                 VarB

After all those are done:

VarA                                                 VarC

Then:

VarB                                                 VarA

and so on until it would reach:

VarC                                                 VarC
```

Essentially, for each combination of baseVar + baseAttr + baseVal, I am trying to count the number of times every other combination occurs. So for example (not related to my table, just a separate example): VarB + Attr2 + value=-1 occurred 29 times and when it occurred 29 times, VarA + Attr1 + value=1 occurred 15 times, VarA + Attr1 + value=-1 occurred 6 times and so on. This would repeat for until I went through all the combination.

Comment: It's not clear to me from question, why `order by` is not good for you...

Comment: I am not sure what order by would do by itself in this situation? I need to get a count of occurrences and group them appropriately.

Comment: I did not understand how `BaseAttrCount()` and `DependAttrCount()` is calculated. Also it seems, like there can be `BaseAttr3` for example (from your description), but in SQL, the table structure is not changing...

Comment: That is the objective, to create a result set from the original to now have BaseAttrCount() and DependAttrCount() columns. There could be a BaseAttr3, but I only want to 2. So Base Variable has 2 attributes associated with it, BaseAttr1 and BaseAttr2

Comment: is the `a weather type table` really just one table? or is it two (or more) tables?

Comment: It is one table. This table is created by another table doing a right join on itself.

Comment: are you still following this?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not fully confident I follow your explanation, I think the following may meet your requirements. It is based on building-up a Cartesian product of all the distinct base variables * the possible values then again with all the distinct dependent variables * the possible values. From your sample data this produces 144 distinct combinations.

Once that exists, left join back to your source data (twice due the non-normalized fields), matching base variables, dependent variables and both the base and dependent values. From there we count using a case expression.

Note your sample data has 18 rows with 2 pairs of values (18 * 2) so a count of 36 for both BaseAttrCount and DependAttrCount is expected.

```
select
      bvar.BaseVar
    , bvar.WhichBaseAttr
    , bval.BaseValue
    , count(case when bvar.WhichBaseAttr = 'BaseAttr1' then bd1.BaseAttr1
                 when bvar.WhichBaseAttr = 'BaseAttr2' then bd1.BaseAttr2
            end)
    + count(case when bvar.WhichBaseAttr = 'BaseAttr1' then bd2.BaseAttr1
                 when bvar.WhichBaseAttr = 'BaseAttr2' then bd2.BaseAttr2
            end) as BaseAttrCount
    , dvar.DependVar
    , dvar.WhichDependAttr
    , dval.DependantValue
    , count(case when dvar.WhichDependAttr = 'DependAttr1' then bd1.DependAttr1
                 when dvar.WhichDependAttr = 'DependAttr2' then bd1.DependAttr2
            end)
    + count(case when dvar.WhichDependAttr = 'DependAttr1' then bd2.DependAttr1
                 when dvar.WhichDependAttr = 'DependAttr2' then bd2.DependAttr2
            end) as DependAttrCount
from (
      select distinct
            BaseVar
          , 'BaseAttr1' as WhichBaseAttr
      from Weather
      UNION ALL
      select distinct
            BaseVar
          , 'BaseAttr2'
      from Weather
      ) as bvar
cross join (
            select -1 as BaseValue UNION ALL select 1 
           ) as bval
cross join(
          select distinct
                DependVar 
              , 'DependAttr1' as WhichDependAttr 
          from Weather
          UNION ALL
          select distinct
                DependVar
              , 'DependAttr2'
          from Weather
          ) as dvar
cross join (
            select -1 as DependantValue UNION ALL select 1 
           ) as dval
left join weather as bd1 on bvar.basevar         = bd1.basevar
                        and bvar.WhichBaseAttr   = 'BaseAttr1'
                        and bval.BaseValue       = bd1.BaseAttr1
                        and dvar.DependVar       = bd1.DependVar
                        and dvar.WhichDependAttr = 'DependAttr1'
                        and dval.DependantValue  = bd1.DependAttr1
left join weather as bd2 on bvar.basevar         = bd2.basevar
                        and bvar.WhichBaseAttr   = 'BaseAttr2'
                        and bval.BaseValue       = bd2.BaseAttr2
                        and dvar.DependVar       = bd2.DependVar
                        and dvar.WhichDependAttr = 'DependAttr2'
                        and dval.DependantValue  = bd2.DependAttr2
group by
      bvar.BaseVar
    , bvar.WhichBaseAttr
    , bval.BaseValue
    , dvar.DependVar
    , dvar.WhichDependAttr
    , dval.DependantValue
order by
      bvar.BaseVar
    , bvar.WhichBaseAttr
    , bval.BaseValue
    , dvar.DependVar
    , dvar.WhichDependAttr
    , dval.DependantValue
;
```

<kbd>[See this SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e72a9/1)</kbd>